# fetching an updated page after scrolling with selenium webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, webdriver

I'm trying to scrape titles and links from a youtube search, using selenium webdriver, and I'm currently iterating over the process until a certain condition turns false. Though I can see the page scrolling when it's launched, the data I get only seems to be from the first page fetched, before scrolling a single time. How can I access the updated data after I've scrolled down?

This is some of my code:

```
driver.get(URL)
while (condition)
// extract data, check for condition and write to csv file
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 10000)")
WebDriverWait(driver, 60)
if (iteration terminating condition)
// terminate iteration
```

Answer (score 1):

It depend on what you're using to extract the data. You can do this with selenium but again if you're extracting lots of data then it's probably not that efficient. Generally selenium should be used as a last resort for getting data you can't get through other means.

Consider the following other sources to get dynamic content.

1. API - Youtube does provide one and it may be worth checking this out. You could use the requests package with this which is more efficient than this.
2. Re-engineering HTTP requests - This is based on the fact that javascript makes an Asynchronous Javascipt and XML (AJAX) request to display information on a page without it being refreshed. If we can theoretically mimic these requests then we can grab the data we wnat. This applies to infinite scrolling, which occurs the the Youtue Website, but it can be used for search forms etc.. A request is made to a server and that response is then displayed on the page with javascript. This is also an efficient way to deal with dynamic content.
3. You could use splash, which pre-renders the pages and can execute javascript which is slightly more efficient than say selenium.
4. Selenium, which you're attempting here. It is meant for automated testing and was never really meant for web scraping. That being said, if it's needed then it's needed. But the downsides are that it is incredibly slow for lots of data and it can be quite brittle. That if the servers take longer to load the pages and the commands are executed then you can run into exceptions you don't want.

If you are thinking of using selenium my advice would be to use as little of selenium as possible. That is if the HTML page is updated when you scroll down, to parse that HTML page with say BeautifulSoup rather than using selenium to grab the data you want. Every single time you use selenium to extract data or scroll, you are making another HTTP request to the server. Selenium works by setting up an HTTP server, a secure connection between the webdriver and chromedriver browser. Browser activity is generated through HTTP requests. So you can imagine if you have a lot of lines of code for extracting data the load on the servers becomes greater.

You could update the `driver.page_source` as you scroll that will change with each scroll attempt and parse the data. The other option which may make more sense would be to wait until it stops scrolling and then get the `driver.page_source`, so you can parse the entire HTML with the data you desire.